# Weird behavior of git switch/checkout if index has same content as target commit

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stage, git-index

Let's create a small local repository:

```bash
git init
echo foo > foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo
git branch bar
echo foo >> foo
git commit -a -m 'another foo'
```

If we do this now, we replace our file `foo` in our *index* as well as in our *working copy* with the one from the branch `bar`:

```bash
git restore --source bar --staged --worktree foo
```

and now we switch to `bar`:

```bash
git switch bar
```

## Expectation

git should refuse the `switch` due to a dirty repository

## Actual behavior

git does the switch and acts like nothing ever happened:

```bash
git status
```

> ```
> On branch bar
> nothing to commit, working tree clean
> ```

---

Even weirder, if we instead just restore to the *index*:

```bash
git restore --source bar --staged foo
```

and switch then:

```bash
git switch bar
```

It will again just do it, but this time with uncommitted changes to `foo`?

```bash
git status
```

> ```
> On branch bar
> Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
>         modified:   foo
> ```

## Questions

- Why does git perform the switch?
- Why doesn't it refuse to switch because of a dirty repository?
- What is happening behind the scenes?
- Where is this behavior documented?

FYI, the same happens with `git checkout`.

---

All I could find in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) is this sentence:

> The operation is aborted however if the operation leads to loss of local changes, [...]

But that doesn't really explain it, since if I do this instead of the `restore` above:

```bash
echo foo >> foo
git add foo
git switch bar
```

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>         foo
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> Aborting
> ```

git **won't** do the switch because of a dirty repository (as expected), even though it theoretically **could** without losing local changes by only updating the *index* and not the *working directory*, as it seemingly does when the *index* already has the desired content for the switch.

Why is there an exception when the index has the same content as the target branch?

Comment: The deepest answer to your question is in the `git read-tree` documentation (see the duplicate). It's horribly complicated, isn't it? 

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate mark. I would have never found the other thread. The other question is quite different, but the answer is actually the exact same! Nice one!